# Is there a way to reliably time a SQL query in Node.js or any other type of function?

Tags: asynchronous, node.js, instrumentation

I'm trying to wrap my head around aysnc functions in node. It there a good way to time how long a DB query takes to run via Node.js.

For the applied usage is to time how long a set of algorithms takes to run. I take the input from one and pipe it into another. Tweaks to the first set could output more or less data. so measuring the response of the overall timing might not be too accurate. I'm trying to measure the run times of each function.

any pointers* about the theory would appreciated trying to learn the concept I think is important!.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a sync context, you'd do the following :

```
 var time = function(fn){
   var start = Date.now();
   fn();
   return start - Date.now()
 }
 // which would be called this way : 
 var elapsed = time(function(){
   // do something
 }
 // do something with elapsed
 // do something else
```

The async version is :

```
 var time = function(fn, cb){
    var start = Date.now();
    fn(null, function(){
      var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
      args.splice(1, 0, Date.now() - start);
      cb.apply(this,args); 
    })
 }
 // which you would use this way: 
 time(function(err, cb){
   // do something
   cb(/* params */);
 }, function(err, elapsed /*, params */){
   // do something with elapsed
   // do something else
 });
```

Of course, you could merge the two functions together, but this gives some useful genericity (you could use it with any function).

Comment: Thank You Adrien! Using splice on args is very smooth. This will help me a great deal in the project I'm trying to hack together!